# How to set background color to fixed in c# GTK mono?

Tags: c#, gtk, monodevelop

I am new to C# Gtk in mono. I have made a window with two buttons with this code :

```
using Gtk;
using Gdk;

class FirstScreen : Gtk.Window
{

public FirstScreen() : base("Buttons")
{
    SetDefaultSize(250, 200);
    SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);

    DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };

    Fixed fix = new Fixed();

    Button btn1 = new Button("Take Photo");

    Button btn2 = new Button("Take Video");

    Gdk.Color col = new Gdk.Color();
    Gdk.Color.Parse("red", ref col);
    fix.(StateType.Normal, col);

    fix.Put(btn1,30, 80);
    fix.Put(btn2, 130, 80);


    Add(fix);
    ShowAll();
}


public static void Main() 
{
    Application.Init();
    new FirstScreen();
    Application.Run();
}
```

}

I Want the Background color of the window or the fixed to be changed .How could we do that Please help?

Answer (score 1):

By default `Gtk.Fixed` doesn't have its own `Gdk.Window` but draws on its parent window and doesn't draw any background. To have it draw a background, just tell it to create its own `Gdk.Window`:

```
fix.HasWindow = true;
```

That's all.

Comment: Hi @fog I have a big problem . Do you have experience in GTK mono can you help me on chat?

Comment: I have a project in c# Gtk# using webcam Can you help?

Comment: @NavdeepSinghBedi yes, but why don't you just ask here on stackoverlow?

Comment: i have wasted about a week searching on google and also asked on stackoverflow no one answers but gives -ve marks...I have developed code for visual C# running on windows but I need it on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You would try use eventbox. And establish your object in box. For example:

```
eventbox.ModifyBg (StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color (0, 0, 0));  //Zeros represent of (r,g,b)
```